# Format string date like this "Mon Sep 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)" with sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Well everything is in the title. How can I format a string with the following date format :

`Mon Sep 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

It's in a Big Query Table within a standard SQL query.

I've started with this `PARSE_DATE("%a %b %j %Y", Date)` but I don't really know how to handle what's left...

thanks !

Comment: Please clarify--is the goal to *parse* a date in that format from a string, or are you trying to *format* a string?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard  The bottom of this is that I want to be able to apply a DATE_DIFF function. I have start_date and end_date column as a string. I want them to be a date format. Is this clearer ? thx !

Comment: I think I understand, but one more point of clarification: is every `start_date` and `end_date` in CEST? Or are there other time zones as well? If there may be others, please provide examples in your question.

Comment: Everything is in CEST.

Comment: See if this answer helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start by simulating this type of data--everything uses CEST, but the days vary:

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT
    FORMAT_DATE('%a %b %d %Y GMT+0200', date) AS start_date,
    FORMAT_DATE('%a %b %d %Y GMT+0200',
                DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL MOD(off, 7) DAY)) AS end_date
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2017-09-01', '2018-04-11', INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AS date WITH OFFSET off
)
SELECT
  start_date,
  end_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`;
```

This gives output that looks like `Fri Oct 06 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200` for `start_date` and `Wed Oct 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200` for `end_date`. Now to parse the date strings, we can use `PARSE_DATE` in conjunction with `REGEXP_EXTRACT`; it's easiest to package the logic into a UDF for reuse in the query:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ConvertToDate(date_string STRING) AS (
  PARSE_DATE('%b %d %Y', REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_string, r'[^ ]+ (.*)00:00:00'))
);
```

Combining it with the sample input, we now have the following query:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ConvertToDate(date_string STRING) AS (
  PARSE_DATE('%b %d %Y', REGEXP_EXTRACT(date_string, r'[^ ]+ (.*)00:00:00'))
);

WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT
    FORMAT_DATE('%a %b %d %Y 00:00:00 GMT+0200', date) AS start_date,
    FORMAT_DATE('%a %b %d %Y 00:00:00 GMT+0200',
                DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL MOD(off, 7) DAY)) AS end_date
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2017-09-01', '2018-04-11', INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AS date WITH OFFSET off
)
SELECT
  ConvertToDate(start_date) AS start_date,
  ConvertToDate(end_date) AS end_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`;
```

This returns real `DATE` values for `start_date` and `end_date`, e.g. `2017-10-06` and `2017-10-11`. To apply this to your own table, remove the `WITH` clause and change the table name as appropriate.